# How to build a sql query that uses full text search if a index exists?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I need to build a sqlserver query that if a text column has a full text index, it will be used, if not, the query will degrade to the O(N²) approach of `LIKE '%word%'`?

I believe the answer will be something like:

```
IF has_full_text_index('mycolumn')
    select mytable_id from mytable where contains(mycolumn, 'word')
ELSE
    select mytable_id from mytable where mycolumn like '%word%'
ENDIF
```

The query will be generated by a program. The query will always have just one word to match. The test to see if a column has a full text index must be quick.

Comment: I guess your question makes no sense to me (probably just missing something). It's your table - shouldn't you know whether there is a full text index on the column ahead of time?

Comment: No, but I didn't want to enter in the complex environment where this code is needed. 

The simplest case to explain is that some users will be using a database without the indexing service enabled and the software must still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I tend to agree with Ken that you will know which of your tables belongs to a fulltext catalog, you can query

```
sp_help_fulltext_tables {catalogname}
```

for the tables in your catalog. (via [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933422(SQL.80).aspx))

Comment: sp_help_fulltext_tables fails if the Full-Text Search isn't enabled for the database

Comment: SELECT fulltextserviceproperty('IsFulltextInstalled')

will return 1 or 0 depending upon whether FullText is running.